# Disassembling a RC car for a Arduino Robot

Tags: arduino-uno, robotics

I am looking at making an Arduino robot car. I have a RC car( photos below). I was wondering if I could take the chassis of the car and modify it to make it Arduino controlled, if so how could I do that?(I have an Arduino UNO R3). I would like to make it into a wall avoiding robot. I have never soldered a thing in my life, and I don't own a soldering iron.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Depends what you want to do? But if you're good with soldering and electrics it should be easy... Tell us what you want your robot to do, and we will try to help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes modifying something can be harder than starting from scratch. This is probably one of those cases, but it is over all not too difficult if you have the courage.

Start with a good example, like [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Obstacle-Avoidance-Robot/) robot.  It will give you an idea of what hardware you must add to your RC car and how to program the Arduino.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Someone has done exactly this, and written detailed instructions at http://www.instructables.com/id/Autonomous-Control-of-RC-Car-Using-Arduino/

Some remote control devices (usually not the really cheap ones, like the one shown here) will have a standard transmitter/receiver. See http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/3-channel-radio-control-receiver-box_311659816.html for a picture of the receiver. If you can find this in your remote control device, you should be able to unplug it, and replace it with an Arduino. You will need the "Servo" library - see https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/servo

You can probably get away without soldering - you will probably need to strip some wires, and you can use crocodile clips, and/or breadboard jumpers to connect everything up. It won't be pretty.

If you want to learn to solder (I know it's intimidating, but it's not so bad) I recommend that you find a local hackspace/makerspace, and find someone there - they will probably be more than happy to teach you. They probably have everything you need, be nice to them, and if you want them to continue, join up & pay regular subs. And take every opportunity to teach the skills you have to anyone else who asks for help.